# Android Studio: Instant run equires that the platform corresponding to your target device (Android UNOFFICIAL Preview) is installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.1-nougat, android-instant-run

I use a Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo (SM-G530FZ) with a custom rom (Android 7.1.1) in it for programming, but everytime I launch my app I get this messages:
[image]
[image]

How can I solve it? This does not appears with my personal phone (stock Android 7.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

To enable instant run on your phone you have to install android 7.1 from sdk manager.

Comment: already did, in fact it works with my personal phone that has stock 7.1.1 rom as I said

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your IDE cannot identify the android platform. It appears your custom ROM did not identify the Android version in its config file.

Try to identify the platform using

```
System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT
```

and download the SDK for that.

Alternatively turn off Instant Run for your development environment, this way you can build your code to your phone the usual way.

Comment: I got this in Logs:
OS version: 25 // device: fortunafz // model: SM-G530FZ // product: aosp_fortunafz...
So this problem is caused by the rom's author? I already have the SDK for API 25

Comment: That would be the most logical conclusion after eliminating all other factors. The ROM identifies the platform as Android UNOFFICIAL Preview.

Answer (score 0):

You have custom ROM installed on your phone and it is in `Preview or Unofficial` phase. (For example, I have installed Android 8.0 Custom ROM on my phone which is still in development phase).

Edit `build.prop` file using ES File explorer or any Root File Explorer (this requires root access).

Open ES File explorer, access folder `\SYSTEM` and navigate to `build.prop` .Select "open with" and select "Text Editor".

Replace `PREVIEW or UNOFFICIAL` with `REL`

> ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0 
>  ro.build.version.codename= REL

Save the file and restart your phone.

As of now (2nd Dec 2017), Android 8.0 is latest [release build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#CODENAME) as per Android SDK. If you don't have 7.1.1 platform tools, Android studio will download those files.

Now, you can use Instant run with your custom ROM.